# About template and object problems with Kirby CMS

Tags: php, kirby

#### I met a few difficult problems when trying to write an API for my blog built with **kirby cms** .

In a template file called "article.php" in kirby,I want to put the values (e.g. "$page->title()") into an array in order to use the function "json_encode()" to render a json result and then output.

The usage of the kirby method (e.g."$page->title()") is as simple as below:

```
echo $page->title();
```

And it can return the title of the current page (e.g."titleOfThisPage").I think(may be wrong,for I am a noob) the value can also be passed to an array in the way like this:

```
$title = array(
"name" => "title",
"value" => $page->title()
);
```

But unfortunately,it doesn't work correctly.

Could you please tell (or teach) me what is wrong,and how can I achieve the aim?

Here enclosed the original code:

```
if($_REQUEST['get'] == "id")
  {
    $json_array = array(
    "status" => "success", 
    "id" => $page->id(), 
   );
   $json_output = json_encode($json_array);
   echo $json_output;
   exit;
  }
  elseif($_REQUEST['get'] == "title")
  {
    $json_array = array( 
    "status" => "success",
    "title" => $page->title(),
   );
   $json_output = json_encode($json_array);
   echo $json_output;
   exit;
  }
```

This is my first post.I am a Chinese high school student but also a blog and code lover.I find it hard to ask such questions in some websites in China,so I come to Stack Overflow.Please help me with any mistakes(not only programing errors,but also English grammar mistakes for I am also studying English at school) in any of my post, **as a noob** I would obviously appreciate it!Hoping for an easy solution coming out soon and a long live in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you have method  $page->title()

Comment: If you replace this code "title" => $page->title(),"  to this  "title" => $page->id(),"  it work correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the way out,just adding the type is OK:

```
  elseif($_REQUEST['get'] == "title")  
  {
    $json_array = array(
     "status" => "success",
     "title" => (string)$page->title(),
   );
   $json_output = json_encode($json_array);
   echo $json_output;
   exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have method $page->title() ??

If you replace this code

```
"title" => $page->title(),"
```

to this

```
"title" => $page->id(),"
```

in this case

```
elseif($_REQUEST['get'] == "title")
```

is it return correct result but using id or not?

Comment: The method of "$page->title()" really exists and below is the result returned from "var_dump($page->title())":

Comment: object(Field)#107 (3) { ["page"]=> string(54) "work-article/site-building/htaccess-index-page-setting" ["key"]=> string(5) "title" ["value"]=> string(33) ".htaccess文件设置网站首页" }

Comment: how you run this request from browser ?

Comment: can you add simple php script only with this code  and run it -  "it work perfectly", I see it !!

Comment: It is just a template file,not a part of the kirby program,how can it be difficult to achieve such simple function?

Comment: Do you really know about the Kirby CMS?

Comment: And how did you think I was telling lies?That is not necessary.

Comment: without cms it is work perfect - problem not in this code, maybe need analyze routing of your CMS. Do you add this  page to routing path in your CMS?

Comment: Yes,and others are alright.But I really do not understand why "$page->id()" returned a string,while "$page->title()" returned an object?

Comment: Below is the result returned from "var_dump($page->id())":string(54) "work-article/site-building/htaccess-index-page-setting"

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding,I updated the question post,please reread it,thank you very much!